# Convert element tags to key value pair in OIC map

Tags: xml, xslt, key-value

Currently i am getting my input payload in this format.

```
<Marks>
<Math>87</Math>
<Science>92</Science>
<History>85</History>
</Marks>
```

Can this be converted to the below format using OIC map. Please suggest.

```
<Marks>
 <Subject>Math</Subject>
 <Value>87</Value>
</Marks>
<Marks>
 <Subject>Science</Subject>
 <Value>92</Value>
</Marks>
<Marks>
 <Subject>History</Subject>
 <Value>85</Value>
</Marks>
```

Any solution to this most welcome.

Comment: This is a rather trivial task, which can be accomplished easily using the `name()` function. Please post your attempt so we can see where you're stuck. Otherwise it looks like you're just looking for someone to write your code for you.

Comment: I am already using local-name() to fetch element name data. But if you see my source is not a repetitive node, so i am unable to loop through and fetch data from each element inside <Marks>.

Comment: I don't see the problem. Why don't you post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.